# How can I have a node spanned over multiple columns push to its cell borders' borders?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to have the (big) node with *Long text long text* span from the very left of cell m-2-2 to the very right of cell m-2-5.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=0.25ex,
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %   text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=1.0cm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40
    },
    phasentext/.style={
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm, 
        %   text width=7cm,
        draw=gray,
        very thick,
        font=\sffamily\small
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
\matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=6mm,
column sep=3mm,
inner sep=7pt
] {
    %
    |[phase]| 1 & & & & \\
    & |[phasentext] (WordA)| Test: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordB)| Stuff:\tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordC)| Stuff text word: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordD)| Some more words: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick] (-3pt,-2pt) -- (3pt,-2pt) -- (0,2pt) -- cycle; \draw[thick] (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt); \end{tikzpicture} \\
};
\node[phase, fit=(m-1-2)(m-1-5), align=left, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex] (Words) {Long text I suppose};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

About the title: feel free to edit it if you can think of a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is your `matrix` before adding long text node and with `empty nodes` drawn. As you can see empty nodes are `empty`, i.e. just nothing with some `inner sep`.

And you can also see why `fit=(m-1-2)(m-1-5)` produces a shorter node than expected. But its size is the correct one, your expectation was wrong ;-)

A possible solution consists in using nodes `WordA` and `WordD` to fix long text node size but aligning it over first row.

```
\node[phase, fit=(WordA)(WordD), align=left, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
      anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (Words) 
      at (m-1-1-|WordA.west) {\ Long text I suppose};
```

In previous line I've added `\` (white space) before node's text because we need to fix `inner sep=0pt` for adjusting fitting node size.

The complete code is

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=0.25ex,
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %   text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=1.0cm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40
    },
    phasentext/.style={
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %node distance=0.5cm,
        rectangle,
        minimum width=2cm,
        minimum height=1cm, 
        %   text width=7cm,
        draw=gray,
        very thick,
        font=\sffamily\small
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
\matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=6mm,
column sep=3mm,
inner sep=7pt,
] {
    %
    |[phase]| 1 & & & & \\
    & |[phasentext] (WordA)| Test: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordB)| Stuff:\tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordC)| Stuff text word: \tikz \draw[thick, circular glow={fill=gray}] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; &
    |[phasentext] (WordD)| Some more words: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=6pt]; \draw[thick] (-3pt,-2pt) -- (3pt,-2pt) -- (0,2pt) -- cycle; \draw[thick] (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt); \end{tikzpicture} \\
};
\node[phase, fit=(WordA)(WordD), align=left, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex, anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (Words) at (m-1-1-|WordA.west) {\ Long text I suppose};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and the final result:

[image]

Comment: The `inner space`-option can be omitted, btw. Also, the option `anchor=west` is crucial as I have found out...

Comment: @henry If you omit `inner sep=0pt`, long text node will be longer (by `2 x inner sep`) than distance `WordD.east - WordA.west`. If you don't mind having a longer node, you can omit this correction. `anchor=west` is crucial here because it fixes the reference point for node. This `node anchor` will be placed where `at` fixes.